# Why is this javascript / css animation only working on the first of its kind and not the rest?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am trying to get multiple different circles to do this transition, but only the first one will trigger the effect (regardless of where the rest are on the page)

javascript

```
let circle = document.querySelector('.circle')

circle.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    if(!circle.classList.contains('hover')){
        circle.classList.add('hover');
    }
})

circle.addEventListener('mouseleave', () =>{
    if(circle.classList.contains('hover')){
        circle.classList.remove('hover');
    }
})
```

css

```
.circle {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: slateblue;
    border-radius: 100px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1) 3s;
}

.hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

html

```
<div class="circle">1</div>
<div class="circle">2</div>
```

edit
Thanks everyone, I was adding way more than I needed, such a simple fix.

Comment: That's because document.querySelector only returns the first matching element.  Instead, loop through the elements returned by document.querySelectorAll and apply the event listeners to each.

Comment: Why aren’t you using `:hover` in CSS? Read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). Use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple event listeners. E.g., use an [event argument](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](/q/1687296/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `let circle = document.querySelector('.circle')`  only selects a single element.

You should use `querySelectorAll` and iterate over the results

```js
const circles = document.querySelectorAll('.circle')

circles.forEach(circle => {
  circle.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    if (!circle.classList.contains('hover')) {
      circle.classList.add('hover');
    }
  })

  circle.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    if (circle.classList.contains('hover')) {
      circle.classList.remove('hover');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.circle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: slateblue;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1) 3s;
}

.hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">1</div>
<div class="circle">2</div>
```

---

But you can accomplish the same with just CSS. Use `.circle:hover` instead of `.circle` in the css rule

```css
.circle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: slateblue;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1) 3s;
}

.circle:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">1</div>
<div class="circle">2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I thing you should use querySelectorAll instead of querySelector, querySelector returns only the first matching element.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, you will need to use `querySelectorAll` and apply your listener to each circle individually. `querySelectorAll` creates an iterable HTML collection.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

```
let circles = document.querySelectorAll('.circle')
circles.forEach(circle => {
  circle.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    if (!circle.classList.contains('hover')) {
      circle.classList.add('hover');
    }
  })

  circle.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    if (circle.classList.contains('hover')) {
      circle.classList.remove('hover');
    }
  })
})
```

However, as mentioned by @Sebastian, the correct way to implement a hover is by using a pseudo class, like:

```
.circle:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Doing this removes the need for all that javascript.